# Format date in php

Tags: php, date, format

PHP date provides formatting for date as follows

```
a for am,pm
```

or

```
A for AM,PM
```

whereas I need as follows:

```
a for a.m., p.m. //including the abbreviation periods.
A for A.M. , P.M.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
$s = array(' am', ' AM', ' pm', ' PM');
$r = array(' a.m.', ' A.M.', ' p.m.', ' P.M.');
$date = str_replace($s, $r, $date);
```

(you could make a function)